# Swapping Objects in an Array - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, swap

In C#, I have an Array of MenuItem. I'm trying to swap the two Objects in index 2 and index 3 of the array without success using the code below:

```
MenuItem Temp = Items[2];  
Items[2] = Items[3];  
Items[3] = Temp;
```

There must be a reason why the second and third lines aren't working in C# which I may not understand yet. Is anyone able to clarify it a bit more? Do I have to go deeper and swap each property in the objects individually?

Edited - Sorry. Looks like I made a mess of the code when trying to clean it up for posting. Corrected now.

The actual code is :

```
MenuItem TempButton = MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId];  
MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId] = MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId + 1];  
MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId + 1] = TempButton;
```

`MenuItems.Items` is an array of `MenuItem`

Looking at the Watch I have placed on MenuItems.Items, nothing happens on Line 2 or 3.

The `MenuItems.Items` property has get and set functions, which may be causing the issue... Will investigate further...

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You seem to be assigning `Temp` and `Items[2]` to each other, effectively swapping nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you refer to `MenuItems.Items[]` in the second line of code, but `Items[]` everywhere else?  And SelectedButton.CountID in line 2, but magic numbers everywhere else?

Comment: I think I know exactly what happened here. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are settings `Items[2]` to `Temp`, which was `Items[2]` to begin with, so you are effectively not doing anything. I don't know what `SelectedButton.CountId` is supposed to be.

But if you just want to swap indices 2 and 3, you can do this:

```
Item Temp = Items[2];
Items[2] = Items[3];
Items[3] = Temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `SelectedButton.CountId` = 2?  if so I would try this:

```
Item Temp = MenuItems.Items[2];  
MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId] = MenuItems.Items[3];  
MenuItems.Items[3] = Temp;
```

Note the last line has a 3 in it.

This would be clearer:

```
Item Temp = MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId];  
MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId] = MenuItems.Items[3];  
MenuItems.Items[3] = Temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `SelectedButton.CountId` is supposed to be but you're putting `Temp` right back in the same slot it was to begin with. And `MenuItems.Items` seems to be a totally different collection from Items.

```
string[] items = { "one", "two", "three" };
string temp = items[1]; // temp = "two"
items[1] = items[2]; // items[1] = "three"
items[2] = temp; // items[2] = "two"

// items is now
// { "one", "three", "two" }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Item Temp = Items[SelectedButton.CountId];   
Items[SelectedButton.CountId] = MenuItems.Items[SelectedButton.CountId+1];   
Items[SelectedButton.CountId+1] = Temp;
```

This should swap in a bubble fashion

Answer (score 1):

I remember running into a similar source of confusion some time ago, with the [`DataRow.ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx) property. This property was extremely counterintuitive for the very same reason that the `Items` property in your example seems so odd.

What was ultimately so confusing was that the property was designed to be *copied from* and *assigned to*, just like you normally would with a field of value type (like `int`, `double`, etc.). That is, to change the element at index 2, this would not work:

```
row.ItemArray[2] = "New Value";
```

The above code would essentially *copy* the values from the row into a new array, take that copy and set the value at index 2 to "New Value," and then the new array would immediately be out of scope. The way this property was *supposed* to work was:

```
object[] items = row.ItemArray;
items[2] = "New Value";
row.ItemArray = items;
```

**Very** counterintuitive, in my book (note to library developers: *don't do this*). But it sounds like this is probably the problem behind the issue you were seeing with your code.

In other words, I think the swapping code you have (now) is correct. The problem lies with whoever had the bright idea of making that `Items` property behave as if it's a value field.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as I wanted to move elements in a WPF-TreeView up and down. Since none of the answers solved the problem for me here is the best I could find.

```
    private void MoveLayerUp()
    {
        if(Layers.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int index = Layers.Items.IndexOf(Layers.SelectedItem);
            if (index > 0)
            {
                var swap = Layers.Items[index - 1];
                Layers.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                Layers.Items.Insert(index, swap);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveLayerDown()
    {
        if (Layers.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int index = Layers.Items.IndexOf(Layers.SelectedItem);
            if (index < Layers.Items.Count-1)
            {
                var swap = Layers.Items[index + 1];
                Layers.Items.RemoveAt(index + 1);
                Layers.Items.Insert(index, swap);
            }
        }
    }
```

This solves the problem of assigning elements in the collection. Further it has the advantage that the current seleced item is never touched and stays selected.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the issue. I think I complicated the problem a bit too much.

MenuItems.Items was a property with get/set functions that returns/sets a private ArrayList.

I created a function in the class for MenuItems which swapped the indexes in the private ArrayList. (which used standard swapping code similar to what I tried and what everyone has mentioned in their replies.)

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Are *you* the developer responsible for the `Items` property? If so I **highly** recommend you change it, as this behavior is only going to confuse other developers if they ever look at this code. (I'm assuming you're not, but the fact that you say "I created a function in the class..." leads me to question that assumption.)

Comment: @DanTao Had a chat with co-workers who are responsible for the class. The private ArrayList contains data that is not meant to be accessible from outside. In fact, it could be disastrous if the ArrayList is modified without certain precautions which member functions like AddItems(), RemoveItems() etc. do. The property was intended to return a copy of the internal data at that instance, and as you suspected, it goes out of scope immediately.

Comment: Modification of the data should only be via member functions, so I'm actually of the opinion that the property should really be turned into a function which returns the relevant data. I think this would prevent other developers from assuming they could (try) assigning data to it...

Comment: Yes, the list should not be exposed this way at all, particularly not with a `set`! Expose the behavior you want to allow: `Add`, `Remove`, etc. If you want to provide a way to get the items without permitting direct manipulation of the `ArrayList`, something like `GetItems` which is explicitly documented as returning a *copy* of the items would be a much better call than an `Items` property, in my opinion.