# Assign values to another position

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Very simple question i have.But trouble on me.

I have below for loop. and i need to assign some values.

```
int i;
for (i = currPos + 1; i < expPos;i++ )
{
    [i + 1] = i;// I want to assign i th position to the i+1 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `[i + 1]`? Do you have an array or something on somewhere else? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Do you need to decrement `i`? Is this what you're looking for: `for (i = currPos + 1; i < expPos; i-- )`? Mind the `i--` instead of `i++`.

Comment: As Soner already said I would be great to give more details about the code (do you have an array, what type is it ?). Do you want to swap `array[i]` value with `array[i+1]`'s ? If that is what you are looking for you need a temporary object as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614785/swapping-objects-in-an-array-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the following:

```
//You would want to create a custom Player class to store this data as it looks silly here but:
        string[] objectNames = { "player1", "player2", "player3", "player4" };
        int[] objectPositionX = { 5, 10, 15, 20 };
        int[] objectPositionY = { 50, 60, 70, 70 };
        for (int i = 0; i < objectNames.Length; i++)
        {
            //An example of this use would be teleporting a player to another player? Say player 2 to player 4's location.
            if(objectNames[i] == "player2")
            {
                objectPositionX[i] = objectPositionX[3];
                objectPositionY[i] = objectPositionY[3];
            }
        }

        //I'm only taking a stab at what you want as the question was a tad vague. But hope this helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood u correctly .Let's assume that u have an array called "A" and u want to set the position of  `A[i+1]=A[i];`
But be aware off losing the data of `[i+1]` index. 
Any way please be more specific.

Comment: Yes i have a array and your understanding is correct.